# Calculation goes south in Excel, works in calculator

Tags: excel

I'm facing a strange issue in Excel. I have a formula and a part of that formula would do:

```
cell value / 88.4 * -1.154
```

So for example when I have a cell value of 75,3 the formula should calculate `75.3 / 88.4 * -1.154` and result to `-0.302...`. Using my calculator this happens. When I try this in Excel I get `-0.982...`

I've checked the data types in the cells, both the cellvalue-cell and outcome-cell are digits.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`75.3 / 88.4 - 1.154` is (approximately) `-0.302` (Note the missing `*`).

But you are evaluating

`75.3 / 88.4 * (-1.154)`

Excel is correct. Note that the unary `-` has a higher operator *precedence* than multiplication, so the parentheses I've added are merely for clarity.

Perhaps your calculator *cancels* the multiplication when you press the minus button!

Comment: your answer was faster than mine :P

Comment: I think you're right. And I wasn't aware that a preceding `-` has a higher order. +1A

Comment: @Ben Normal mathematics multiplication and division have a higher priority than addition and subtraction.  Read this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)  The important part to read though is the exceptions where they talk about unary and MS Excel

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with excel. Even in calculator, you are getting the same result as excel. Calculate LEFT to RIGHT or put appropriate brackets.